# 200/CHDIR Systemmd Service UBUNTU

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, ssh

My .net core project is in

```
/var/netcore/
```

I create service

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/AspNetServer.service
```

Body

```
[Unit]
Description=ASP .NET Web Application
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/netcore
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /root/var/netcore/PersonalBlog.Web.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=netcore-demo
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after enable and start services, then status, and I catch the error

```
 AspNetServer.service - ASP .NET Web Application
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/AspNetServer.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-05-25 00:03:30 MSK; 322ms ago
    Process: 3065 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /root/var/netcore/PersonalBlog.Web.dll (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
   Main PID: 3065 **(code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)**

May 25 00:03:30 31-31-199-190.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: AspNetServer.service: Main process exited, code=exit>
May 25 00:03:30 31-31-199-190.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: AspNetServer.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm trying to deploy my first .net core project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I change User=www-data to User=ubuntu name of my server ubuntu@ubuntu-server, it helped me to run.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).